# Fitting img in DIV using vw in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I want to center and scale an `img` into a `div` who is set up with the width in vw. If I set the width of the `.box` on `img` to 100% it doesn't scale the `img` to the `div`.

```
.container{
    width:100vw;
    height:auto;
    min-height:70vh;
    background-color:blue;  
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.box{
    width: calc(100vw / 4 );
    padding:10px;
    color:red;
}

.box img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Also when I set the width of .box on 100% it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add code to snippet, so that its easy to solve

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
.box img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to fit an image into a parent container:

```
.image-parent {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 70vw;
}

.fit-height {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: -100%;
    bottom: -100%;
    left: -100%;
    right: -100%;

    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.fit-width {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: -100%;
    bottom: -100%;
    left: -100%;
    right: -100%;

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

it will always fit into the parent container, just give the container `height`and `width`

UPDATED the fiddle for 8 images. instead of a given height you can use `height: 0` and a `padding-bottom: 25%` for instance.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/71o9jg05/2/)

Comment: You use overflow:hidden, it will not scale the img ?

Comment: it will center the image and blow it up / scale it to fit it's parent container to the minimum width/height (whichever you use)

Comment: How do I link the .fit-height and width at the image? (I'm new here and see not the opportunity to put code in a comment)

Comment: just give the `<img>` tag the class `fit-height` as you can see in the JSFIDDLE i added in my answer

Comment: Then I get 5 of the 8 images at the left side at 50% of the screen 2 by 2

Comment: what?! :D sorry , i dont understand what you want

Comment: Yes, i know my explication is not quiet clear, sorry for that. So I have 8 images in 8 boxes. with the solution you give, I putted the 100% on 25% . And then I see 5 of the 8 images. Can I put a printscreen in a comment?